# Subject + To Be + To + Another verb expressing order

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, modality

Could I say something along the lines of

> "You are to tell no one" (I saw this one in the Invencible comic book by the way)

Instead of

> "You must tell no one"

Or even

> "You mustn't tell anyone"?

Just to add other examples:

> You're to keep this information strictly confidential (some book I read a white ago)

> You are not to leave this room

Note: Usually I see this structure being used with characters in a high position of power compared to the person he is talking to.

Comment: It's good English. It forms an instruction, so it can sound bossy if you are not the boss, the parent, the teacher. "You are to tell X" means you will do that, you must do that, you are required to do that. It substitutes for a future tense: "You are to finish your plate and like it."

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yosef!